# Why does my parallel traversal Haskell program leak memory?

Tags: haskell, memory-leaks, space-leak

Consider the following Haskell program (I'm doing this mostly for learning purposes):

```
import qualified Control.Concurrent.MSem as Sem
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import Control.Concurrent (forkIO)
import Control.Monad

-- Traverse with maximum n threads
parallelTraverse :: Foldable a => Int -> (b -> IO()) -> a b -> IO ()
parallelTraverse n action values = do
  sem <- Sem.new n
  forM_ values $ \value -> Sem.with sem (forkIO $ action value)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  let nThreads = read . head $ args :: Int
  parallelTraverse nThreads print [(1::Int)..]
```

when I run it, memory quickly climbs to several GB. I tried various combinations to make sure I discard the results of intermediate computations (the print actions). Why is it still leaking space?

Comment: You have not prevented an unbounded number of threads from running simultaneously. Read your program carefully.

Comment: @ReidBarton : I think I get it: forkIO returns immediately, making the semaphore useless. Back to the design table :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you have an evident mistake in the following piece:

```
Sem.with sem (forkIO $ action value)
```

You're addressing the semaphore from the master thread around the "fork" operation instead of the action there. Following is the proper way to implement it:

```
forkIO (Sem.with sem (action value))
```

I.e., to address the semaphore from the context of the forked thread.

Secondly, in the following code you're calling the `parallelTraverse` operation on an infinite list:

```
parallelTraverse nThreads print [(1::Int)..]
```

Which results in the infinite forking of threads. And since the `forkIO` operation is roughly instantaneous for the calling thread, it's pretty much no surprise that you're running out of resources quite soon.

---

To use the semaphore to limit the number of worker threads the `with` pattern simply won't do in your case. Instead you should use the explicit combination of `wait` and `signal` and not forget to treat the exceptions properly (in case you expect them). E.g.,:

```
parallelTraverse :: Foldable a => Int -> (b -> IO()) -> a b -> IO ()
parallelTraverse n action values = do
  sem <- Sem.new n
  forM_ values $ \value -> do
    Sem.wait sem
    forkIO $ finally (action value) (Sem.signal sem)
```

Comment: My goal is to limit the number of concurrent threads, but now I see why it doesn't work. The infinite list is by design, because I'd like my program to be able to handle an infinite stream of actions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just needed a little extra help to understand that I needed wait and signal on the two sides of forkIO, which is why (if I understand correctly) with can't be used in this case.